# How to remove this Grid type lines?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
    SizedBox(height: 10), // Adding some spacing between the two containers
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        width: 348,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 10),
              child: Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset(0, 8),
                child: Text(
                  "Basic Care",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 3),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Reliable pediatric care within 15 minutes.",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 45,
                  height: 10,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.green, // Green color for the checkbox
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: Checkbox(
                      value: true,
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                      checkColor: Colors.white,
                      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Text(
                    "Instant answers on WhatsApp by Pediatricians (8AM-10PM).",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 14,),
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 45,
                  height: 10,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.green, // Green color for the checkbox
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: Checkbox(
                      value: true,
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                      checkColor: Colors.white,
                      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Text(
                    "Unlimited free pediatric consultaions (8AM - 10PM)",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 14,),
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 45,
                  height: 10,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.green, // Green color for the checkbox
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: Checkbox(
                      value: true,
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                      checkColor: Colors.white,
                      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Text(
                    "Free postpartum yoga classes",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 14,),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                    child: Text(
                      "\u20B9999",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                    child: Text(
                      "Per Month",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15,),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 9),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Color(0xFF9334EA),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  minimumSize: Size(330, 45),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "Get Started",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 17,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
              offset: Offset(0, 4),
              blurRadius: 4,
              spreadRadius: 2,
            ),
          ],
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.white,  // Set the border color to white
            width: 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    const SizedBox(height: 20),
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        width: 348,
        // height: 450,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 10),
              child: Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset(0, 8),
                child: Text(
                  "Basic Care",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 3),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Reliable pediatric care within 15 minutes.",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 45,
                  height: 10,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.green, // Green color for the checkbox
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: Checkbox(
                      value: true,
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                      checkColor: Colors.white,
                      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Text(
                    "Instant answers on WhatsApp by Pediatricians (8AM-10PM).",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 14,),
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 45,
                  height: 10,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.green, // Green color for the checkbox
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: Checkbox(
                      value: true,
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                      checkColor: Colors.white,
                      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Text(
                    "Unlimited free pediatric consultaions (8AM - 10PM)",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 14,),
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 45,
                  height: 10,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.green, // Green color for the checkbox
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: Checkbox(
                      value: true,
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                      checkColor: Colors.white,
                      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Text(
                    "Free postpartum yoga classes",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 14,),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                    child: Text(
                      "\u20B9999",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                    child: Text(
                      "Per Month",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15,),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 9),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Color(0xFF9334EA),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  minimumSize: Size(330, 50),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "Get Started",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 17,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
  ],
),
```

[image: User interface with all elements outlined in blue gridlines]

I have done flutter clean and rebuilt the project but I'm still getting these annoying grid lines. I don't understand why I'm getting this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's happing because of [debugPaintSizeEnabled](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugPaintSizeEnabled.html) Property,

See if you have made it true from anywhere in your code like below:

```
void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: HomeScreen()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  // Disable the debugShowMaterialGrid.
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      debugShowMaterialGrid: false,
      home: const HomeScreenUI(),
    ),
  ); 
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?